# Regex to test if all characters have same case

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input which can accept all alphabetical characters [a-zA-Z] (lower case AND upper case).
I have to attach a validator to this input to test if all characters have same case or not.

For example :

- ABCD is valid
- abcd is valid
- AbCD is invalid
- aBcd is invalid

Is there a way to do that with a regex ? Or should I use a custom function to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, all letters need to be either upper or lower case

```
(^[a-z]+$|^[A-Z]+$)
```

Comment: You can even take the `^$` out: `^([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```js
let string = "hello"
const isOneCase = (string) => /^[a-z]*$|^[A-Z]*$/.test(string)

console.log(isOneCase(string))
```